# почему бот нереагирует на сообщения другого бота

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

я не хотел заморачиваться и решил сделать себе жизнь проще
мой бот пишет в чат сообщение !play (url) но rhythm не реагирует на его смс

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(usr, before, after):
    if ((before.channel and usr not in before.channel.members) or not before.channel) and\
            after.channel and usr in after.channel.members and\
            usr.guild.get_role(828681693954572288) in usr.roles:
            
            url_1 =  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snvQsW15mZE"
            await bot.get_channel(chat3).send(f"!play {url_1}")
            return
```

Comment: Скорее всего бот `rhythm` запрограммирован на игнорирование сообщений от ботов, чтобы люди, добавляя его на свои сервера не нагружали заскриптованными командами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бот `Rhythm`, как и другие популярные боты, запрограммирован на игнорирование сообщений от других ботов.

Поэтому всё-таки легче будет написать команду самому)